# EXTJS 4.1 locking grid column alignment issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have an EXTJS 4.1 locking grid.It shows two vertical scrollbars....one for locked columns and other for unlocked columns.Both these vertical scrollbar scroll down and up simultaneously.There also exists a horizontal scrollbar for unlocked columns.Due to presence of one horizontal bar in unlocked column side,the vertical bar for locked columns scrolls down to full length while the other scrollbar still has some space left to scroll down ie. the space created due to horizontal scrollbar. This creates alignment issue between the data in locked columns and the corresponding data in unlocked columns.
How to solve this alignment issue in EXTJS 4.1 locking grid.
PS: I have already tried all possible solutions mentioned in some sites but none of them worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/162e, check this link hope it will help you with sample locking grid example code.

**Note : Open in crome browser**